# Filtering complex object inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I want to filter object inside nested ng-repeat.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedCityId" />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="shop in shops">
      <p ng-repeat = "locations in shop.locations | filter:search" style="display: block">
          City id: {{ locations.city_id }}
          <span style="padding-left: 20px; display: block;" ng-repeat="detail in locations.details | filter:item">Pin code: {{detail.pin}}</span>
      </p>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.search = function (location) {

        if ($scope.selectedCityId === undefined || $scope.selectedCityId.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }

           if (location.city_id === parseInt($scope.selectedCityId)) {
               return true;
            }
    };

    $scope.item = function (detail) {

        if ($scope.selectedCityId === undefined || $scope.selectedCityId.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (detail.pin == parseInt($scope.selectedCityId)) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $scope.shops =
    [
       {
          "category_id":2,
          "locations":[
             {
                "city_id":368,
                "details": [{
                    "pin": 627718,
                  "state": 'MH'
                }]
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "name":"xxx",
          "category_id":1,
          "locations":[
             {
                "city_id":400,
                "region_id":4,
                "details": [{
                    "pin": 627009,
                  "state": 'MH'
                },{
                    "pin": 129818,
                    "state": 'QA'
                }]
             },
          ]
       },
    ];

});
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/suCWn/210/

I want to use multiple filter inside ng-repeat.

Example: Whenever user enters the ID in the input box. The list should filter based on cityID or PinCode.
if user enter '129818' it should show pin code result of 129818 along with its parent cityID 
Similarly, if a user enter 400, the list should filter and show cityID result with 400 along with its child pin code.

EDIT:

Update Code http://codepen.io/chiragshah_mb/pen/aZorMe?editors=1010]

Answer (score 6):

First, you must not filter locations with matching details. Use something like this in the `search` filter:

```
$scope.search = function (location) {
    var id = parseInt($scope.selectedCityId);
    return isNaN(id) || location.city_id === id || 
           location.details.some(function(d) { return d.pin === id });
};
```

To show details if filtered by cityID, you have to find the parent `location` and check if it was filtered.

```
$scope.item = function (detail) {
    var id = parseInt($scope.selectedCityId);
    return isNaN(id) || detail.pin === id || locationMatches(detail, id);
};

function locationMatches(detail, id) {
    var location = locationByDetail(detail);
    return location && location.city_id === id;
}

function locationByDetail(detail) {
    var shops = $scope.shops;
    for(var iS = 0, eS = shops.length; iS != eS; iS++) {
      for(var iL = 0, eL = shops[iS].locations.length; iL != eL; iL++) {
        if (shops[iS].locations[iL].details.indexOf(detail) >= 0) {
          return shops[iS].locations[iL];
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**EDIT** Another, more flexible solution would be to remove all the filters from ngRepeats and do the filtering in a method that you call on ngChange of the search text. Here is the basic structure for this approach.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) { 
  var defaultMenu = [];
  $scope.currentMenu = [];
  $scope.searchText = '';

  $http.get(/*...*/).then(function (menu) { defaultMenu = menu; } );

  $scope.onSearch = function() {
    if (!$scope.searchText) {
      $scope.currentMenu = defaultMenu  ;
    }
    else {
      // do your special filter logic here...
    }
  };
});
```

And the template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="onSearch()" />
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in currentMenu">
      ...   
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Filtering through city id should also show it's pin code.

Comment: @chiragshah Should it hide the other children, if searched by pin code?

Comment: Yes. It should hide other children

Comment: @chiragshah A little bit ugly, but should work. (for some reason, i cannot update the fiddle anymore...)

Comment: Seems working well. The only problem is $scope.shops is updated ($http response object) once after initial page load which disables the item filter for some reason. Can you provide a fiddle for the same ?

Comment: @chiragshah Can you provide a fiddle? I can't reproduce such behaviour.

Comment: Update codepen [http://codepen.io/chiragshah_mb/pen/aZorMe?editors=1010] 

This contains the actual complex object. Before the user interaction starts the $scope.defaultmenu is updated ($http request - response updates it).

Now I want a three level hierarchy where the user search on the basis on Category, Group & Item (See the fiddle). I haven't change the code. Just changed the HTML & object. Please help me with it.

Comment: @chiragshah if a category matches, you want to see all it's groups and items (event if they don't match)? if a group matches you want to see all it's items? if an item matches, you don't want to see non matching items in this group? Is this the desired behaviour?

Comment: The desired behaviour :
If CATEGORY matches :- 
All of its groups & items must be seen.

If GROUP matches :-
All of its item, Only Its category And no other group in that category must be seen.

If ITEM matches:

Only its category, group (of that item only) & the item itself must be seen.

Comment: @chiragshah I think you should implement the filter logic in a function that updates the whole menu at once. This is the most flexible approach. I edited my answer. I believe that you can add your special logic on your own.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113128/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-hansmaad).

Comment: As per your comment 
"The only problem is $scope.shops is updated ($http response object) once after initial page load which disables the item filter for some reason." I think you are trying to use 2nd approch. Then on ajax call response you need to call `$scope.onSearch()` again to update the filtered list.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated your filters. The problem is in your `search` filter you are only checking for the city_id, what you should do is:

1. Check if the typed id is city_id
2. Check if typed id is a `pid` of a child detail of given location

Similar thing for the `item` filter:

1. Check if the typed id is a `pid` of the detail being filtered
2. Check if the typed id is a `city_id` of the parent location of the detail passed in

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nw3bfn8c/4/). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

By simply modifying the `JSON` to include the `city_id` for children so you don't need to loop through it to get the parent's `city_id`, the solution is as easy as this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.search = function (location) {
        if (!$scope.selectedCityId)
            return true;
        //if user's input is contained within a city's id
        if (location.city_id.toString().indexOf($scope.selectedCityId) > -1)
            return true;
        for (var i = 0; i < location.details.length; i++)
            //if user's input is contained within a city's pin
            if (location.details[i].pin.toString().indexOf($scope.selectedCityId) > -1)
                return true;
    };

    $scope.item = function (detail) {
        if (!$scope.selectedCityId)
            return true;
        //if user's input is contained within a city's id
        if (detail.city_id.toString().indexOf($scope.selectedCityId) > -1)
            return true;
        //if user's input is contained within a city's pin
        if (detail.pin.toString().indexOf($scope.selectedCityId) > -1)
            return true;
    };
```

Modified JSON

```
$scope.shops=[{"category_id":2,"locations":[{"city_id":368,"details":[{"city_id":368,"pin":627718,"state":'MH'}]}]},{"name":"xxx","category_id":1,"locations":[{"city_id":400,"region_id":4,"details":[{"city_id":400,"pin":627009,"state":'MH'},{"city_id":400,"pin":129818,"state":'QA'}]},]},];});
```

If directly modifying the `JSON` is not possible, you can modify it like this in this controller directly after this `$scope.shops = ...json...` statement:

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.shops.length; i++)
    for(var j=0, cat=$scope.shops[i]; j<cat.locations.length; j++)
        for(var k=0, loc=cat.locations[j]; k<loc.details.length; k++)
            loc.details[k].city_id=loc.city_id;
```

Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/87e314a0/

Comment: http://codepen.io/chiragshah_mb/pen/aZorMe?editors=1010]


This is the actual use case. Can you provide solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make the solution easier to understand :

index.html :

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search.city_id" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="shop in shops">
          <p ng-repeat = "locations in shop.locations | filter:search.city_id" style="display: block">
              City id: {{ locations.city_id }}
              <span style="padding-left: 20px; display: block;" ng-repeat="detail in locations.details | filter:item">Pin code: {{detail.pin}}</span>
          </p>    
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

app.js :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.shops =
[
   {
      "category_id":2,
      "locations":[
         {
            "city_id":368,
            "details": [{
                "pin": 627718,
              "state": 'MH'
            }]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"xxx",
      "category_id":1,
      "locations":[
         {
            "city_id":400,
            "region_id":4,
            "details": [{
                "pin": 627009,
              "state": 'MH'
            },{
                "pin": 129818,
                            "state": 'QA'
            }]
         },
      ]
   },
];


});
```

Here's the fiddle : 
[mySolution](http://jsfiddle.net/pcvaxeun/)